# Small angle approximation on cosine

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, approximation

The problem is

> Using the small angle approximation of cosine, show that $3-2\cos(x)+4\cos^2(x)\approx 5-kx^2$ where k is a positive constant

I did solve it by using $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$ on the $\cos^2(x)$, by plugging $\sin^2(x)\overset{x\to 0}{\approx}x^2$ and $\cos(x)\overset{x\to 0}{\approx}1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ to get $$3-2(1-\frac{x^2}{2})+4(1-x^2)=5-3x^2$$ hence $k=3$. But why does using $\cos^2(x)\overset{x\to 0}{\approx}(1-\frac{x^2}{2})^2$ doesn't work out? I originally tried plugging that into the $\cos^2(x)$ but got another complete thing. why?

Comment: What "complete other thing" did you get?  The approximation you suggest should have worked.  We can't show you your mistake if you don't show us what you did.

Comment: You can also use $4\cos ^2 x = 2 + 2\cos (2x)$ to get rid of squaring.

Comment: let me post my work, $$3-2(1-\frac{x^2}{2})+4(1-\frac{x^2}{2})^2$$ $$3-2+x^2+4(1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{4})$$ $$1+x^2+4-4x^2+x^4$$ $$x^4-3x^2+5$$

Comment: "got another complete thing": you must tell us which.

Comment: the one i just posted? @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly subbing $\cos^2x=(1-x^2/2+\cdots)^2$ should work out, provided you expand properly:
$$\cos^2x=1-2(x^2/2)+\dots=1-x^2+\cdots$$
$$1-\sin^2x=1-(x-\cdots)^2=1-x^2+\cdots$$

Comment: what are the dots for? can you show how it should work, because i didn't get to the answer by that method at all, i can post my unsuccessful working if you want.

Comment: @Xetrez Dots indicate $x^3$ or higher terms, which we don't need. If you had thrown away the $x^4$ - because the question only required expanding to $x^2$ - you would have got it.

Comment: so is it because this is an approximation, and x^4 when x tends to 0, are smaller and negligible than for example an x^2?

Comment: @Xetrez Yes.${}$

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply forgot to plug $cos\theta \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ in for both $cos\theta$ and $cos\theta^2$ in the expression.

Comment: i posted my working at a post above this one on the comment section, you may want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor, as the function is even the development to second order is $f(0)+\dfrac{f''(0)}2x^2$ or

$$(3-2\cos(0)+4\cos^2(0))+(2\cos(0)+8\sin^2(0)-8\cos^2(0))\frac{x^2}2.$$

Comment: I'm just wondering; would it be more appropiate to say "By Macluarin" or is "By Taylor" also fine as obviously it's a generalisation of Maclaurin series?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: on this site Taylor seems to be the preferred name in all cases, though Maclaurin is indeed more specific to this case. As you can trade one for the other by a simple shift of the variable, the distinction is unimportant.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.